# Power Surge on Hub Port Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, usb

Long story short I am using an Xbox one controller on my windows 7, and it generally works very well, but today it says "Power Surge on Hub Port", and sometimes it makes my keyboard and mouse freeze up/ stop working. The computer makes the 'Device found' noise, and then constantly plays the Device Ejected noise.

And with that, I can't use my Xbox controller.
I used 3 different USB cables, 5 different ports (3 USB 2.0, 2 USB 3.0), one of the 2.0 ports are behind the PC.
I have also tried using an extension cable.
No luck. 
I have restarted my PC many times as well.**How do I fix this?**

Comment: Possibilities are that you have connected too many devices on one port exceeding the available power of the port, or that something is bent/broken and making contact where it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem has effect on other USB devices and occurs on all other ports, it looks like your Windows PC has developed a problem with USB VBUS power supply net, either a protection polyfuse has partially died, or some other circuit.

What you need to test this hypothesis is to apply a 5 Ohm resistor load to any USB ports and measure the resulting voltage. If it goes below 5.0 or 4.9 V, then the common USB power went bad. If you have not enough skills to follow the power drop and determine which board element is at fault, your mainboard needs a replacement.